# Done status based on action in OpenAI Atari

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, atari-2600

I am attempting to create a neural network to play the emulated atari game "BreakoutDeterministic". The action space for the game is [0,1,2,3].

When inputting

```
frame, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
```

The game will play out and and the "is_done" variable will eventually be set to `True` (when the game ends)

When inputting

```
frame, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(3)
```

The game will end but done will not be set to `True`. Instead I have to manually end the process.

**Any explanation to why this happens and how I can fix it?**

Full code:

```
import gym

env = gym.make('BreakoutDeterministic-v4')
frame = env.reset()
env.render()

is_done = False
while not is_done:
  frame, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
  #frame, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(3)
  env.render()
```

Comment: Thought it's something to do with the recently updated version. No luck after rolling back though. It starts fine, but then after a few training iterations done is never true. Every session is forcefully interrupted.